# Hamburgermenu not showing after clicking on the icon. What can I do?

Tags: html, css, header, shopify, hamburger-menu

I ran into a problem as I tried to use the hamburger-menu not only for mobile but for all devices with max 1100px. I am using the shopify debut theme. At first everything went fine. I saw the hamburger-menu and could click on it. But as soon as my window has a pixelcount of 750 to 1100 I can click on the hamburger icon, but nothing shows up. This looks like [this (between 750 and 1100px)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tRUH.png).
Instead it should look like [this (below 750px)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjgWx.png).

I already changed the `@media only screen and (max-width:750px)` to the 1100px and the `@media only screen and (min-width:749px)` to 1099px inside my theme.css for pretty much every header class. Which made the hamburger icon show up. But now I hit a roadblock. I don't know what I am missing here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Just in case you need any of these:

My Website URL: [www.snow-pearl.com](http://www.snow-pearl.com) (without any chances to the @media because it is the live version and I dont want to publish something that is not working)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/RemoZemp/cb8ca87a47b2f9d91dc1db9e6cdd42ca) is the edited `theme.css` file (with changes).
[Here](https://gist.github.com/RemoZemp/d661922912699ffd76df9e632d10202b) is the used `theme.js` file.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/RemoZemp/a60ab5a475874d9179d3a0f40289d111) is the edited `header.liquid` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your hamburger isn't showing is due to line number 800 in theme.css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 750px){
    .medium-up--hide {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked for me. I truly appreciate that you invested your time to solve my problem.